# Loop difficulty

Tags: java, loops

Got some information from answers from suggested question and edited my code. Now I get an error with **||** operator. What is wrong there? What is right way for writing this.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String shapeName;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please identify the shape");
            System.out.print("Rectangle (Press R) / Circle (Press C): ");

            shapeName = input.next();

        } while (!shapeName.equals("R") || !shapeName.equals("C"));
```

Comment: just put the code from the input in a loop `while(True)`and exit (e.g. *break*) that loop in the valid cases

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what is wrong with your code (i.e. that it doesn't exit the loop), because if you say you "get an error" people expect that you get a runtime exception or a compile-time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the condition with the `while` statement is wrong.

Replace

```
while (!shapeName.equals("R") || !shapeName.equals("C"));
```

with

```
while (!(shapeName.equals("R") || shapeName.equals("C")));
```

**--OR--**

```
while (!shapeName.equals("R") && !shapeName.equals("C"));
```

In case of conditions combined using `||`, the next condition in this combination is checked only when a condition evaluates to `false` i.e. as soon as a condition evaluates to `true`, next conditions in the combination are not checked and the combination evaluates to `true`.

In case of conditions combined using `&&`, the next condition in this combination is checked only when a condition evaluates to `true` i.e. as soon as a condition evaluates to `false`, next conditions in the combination are not checked and the combination evaluates to `false`.

### What is wrong with your condition?

Let's see how your conditions are producing an undesirable result.

When the user enters `R`, your condition will evaluate as follows

```
while (!shapeName.equals("R") || !shapeName.equals("C")); => while (false ||  !shapeName.equals("C")); => while (false ||  true); => while (true);
```

When the user enters `C`, your condition will evaluate as follows

```
while (!shapeName.equals("R") || !shapeName.equals("C")); => while (true ||  !shapeName.equals("C")); => while (true);
```

Thus, using your condition, despite the user enters the desired input, the `while` condition is forcing it to loop back.

Now, try doing the same exercise using the `while` conditions I have suggested in the answer.

Comment: Actually the option with && working ok. But 2nd option what you wirte with || operator is not working. Program exit when I input R or C. But && option is ok

Comment: @BahramAfandi - Both the suggested conditions behave the same way and are correct i.e. they will force the user to enter again if the input is not `C` or `R`. If the user enters `C` or `R`, they will not force the user for input.

Comment: Yes you are right my bad sory. Thank you very much. SOLVED!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you have this concept of 'ask for a selection of options, and if none of the available options is chosen, tell the user about that, and prompt again'.

That's a bunch of work. So make a method.

```
public static String pick(Scanner scanner, String prompt, String... options) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        String choice = scanner.next();
        for (String option : options) {
            if (option.equals(choice)) return choice;
        }
        System.out.println("Error - that is not an available choice.");
    }
}
```

and to use:

```
String choice = pick(scanner,
  "Please identify the shape\nRectangle (R) / Circle (C): ",
  "R", "C");
```

Comment: but being back need to test again *choice*  to do the expected associated actions, it is more simple to put code in `while(True)`and use `break` to exit the loop after the expected actions when valid

Comment: Thank you for information. I edited now my question due to getting informations from another suggested question. Now another difficulty..

Comment: Okay, so you didn't do what I suggested, and edited the question to be a completely different question. Please review SO guidelines first before using the service. Thank you!

Comment: @rzwitserloot Sorry, I'll take it into account next time. But I checked what you suggested. It does not  help at all. Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      char ch2;
  do{
      char choice;
      System.out.println("Please identify the shape"); 
      System.out.print("Rectangle (Press R) / Circle (Press C): ");
      choice=input.next().charAt(0);
switch(choice){
    case 'R':
       System.out.println("Do first operation bla bla bla");
      break;
  case 'C':
    System.out.println("Do second operation bla bla bla");
    break;
  default:
       System.out.println("ERROR");
       break;
}
System.out.println("do u want to continue enter y/n");
 ch2=input.next().charAt(0);
}
while((ch2!='n')&& (ch2!='N'));
}
```